# How to transform style="{{data.something}}" to show up in IE?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I currently have this:

```
<div class="row status green" ng-repeat="green in report.data.green" style="{{green.image}}">
```

but the style is not showing up in IE. How can I solve these? *green.image* contains the following:

```
image = "background: linear-gradient(rgba("+ colordb[color] +",0.5), rgba("+ colordb[color] +",0.5)), url('../images/" + db[id][1] + "'); background-size: 100% 100%; background-size: cover;";
```

Comment: Try using `ng-style="green.image"`

Comment: Also which version of IE? linear-gradient is supported from 10+
http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Comment: IE11, it does not show anything if I do ng-style="green.image"

Comment: sorry my bad, ng-style needs to be and object where keys are the css property and values the actual value, try changing image to an object with background as a property and the rest as the value and check.

Comment: I have changed things to: `ng-style="{'background':green.image}"` and `image = "linear-gradient(rgba("+ colordb[color] +",0.5), rgba("+ colordb[color] +",0.5)), url('../images/" + db[id][1] + "');"` but I still doesn't show anything.

Comment: you have background-size: 100% 100%; background-size: cover;

Comment: I now have this `ng-style="{'background':'linear-gradient(rgba('+green.color+',0.5),rgba('+green.color+',0.5)), url(\'../images/'+green.image+'\')','background-size':'cover'}"` but I need to hide all if I have an empty image `(green.image)`. Finally, I need both the `background-size: 100% 100%` and `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angular's Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

> AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our
>   blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team
>   does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or
>   earlier.

And in your case I assume you're having angular `1.3+` version. So

Use ng-style tags instead of `style="{{ someCss }}"`. The latter works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in `Internet Explorer <= 11` (the most recent version at time of writing).

If you're getting the problem again then you should inject the `ngRoute` service in your app init. I'd the same problem in `IE` and this trick worked for me

Your app init code should be

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

.run(['$route', function ($route) {
            }])
.controller('MyCntrl', MyCntrl)
```